# cocos2d-x using_ns_cc

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need to know what is the functionality of this sentence in Cocos2D-X in C++:

```
USING_NS_CC
```

Example in code:

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#include "GameOverScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

HelloWorld::~HelloWorld()
{
    if (_targets)
    {
        _targets->release();
        _targets = NULL;
    }

    if (_projectiles)
    {
        _projectiles->release();
        _projectiles = NULL;
    }

    // cpp don't need to call super dealloc
    // virtual destructor will do this
}
```

Answer (score 6):

According to cocos2d-x source code macro is an equivalent of `using namespace cocos2d`.

You can check it on your own in [CCPlatformMacros.h](https://github.com/hopstertv/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/platform/CCPlatformMacros.h) in cocos2d-x repository:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define NS_CC_BEGIN                     namespace cocos2d {
    #define NS_CC_END                       }
    #define USING_NS_CC                     using namespace cocos2d
    #define NS_CC                           ::cocos2d
#else
    #define NS_CC_BEGIN 
    #define NS_CC_END 
    #define USING_NS_CC 
    #define NS_CC
#endif
```

In response to @rene answer, I checked "Learning Cocos2d-x Game Development" from author Siddharth Shekar and the author is wrong.

[Here is a link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=sGOZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT62&lpg=PT62&dq=using_ns_cc&source=bl&ots=dLHOqcGGSr&sig=cjejRrs6VKpOp57H9X6GHtF2woo&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBjgKahUKEwjm2uv4jbDIAhXCWxoKHU0sBO4#v=onepage&q=using_ns_cc&f=false) to that paragraph from this book, [here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3UiZ.png) of the paragraph.

What he wrote wrong about `USING_NS_CC`:

- **it doesn't "`#include CCPlatformMacros.h`" and it doesn't load additional macros**

  To use it you need to include `CCPlatformMacros.h` directly by adding
  `#include <cocos/CCPlatformMacros.h>` or indirectly by adding other header that contains it, e.g. `#include <cocos2d.h>`.
- **it doesn't set the namespace to `cocos2d`**

  It includes all symbols from `cocos2d` namespace, what makes that you can use cocos2d-x symbols without pointing the right `cocos2d::`.

  To set a namespace `cocos2d` for you symbols you should use

  ```
  namespace cocos2d
  {
    // some declarations/definitions
  }
  ```

  or equivalent:

  ```
  NS_CC_BEGIN

    // some declarations/definitions

  NS_CC_END
  ```

  But remember that adding your own symbols to external library is strongly not recommended.

Comment: do you know what is the difference between "namespace cocos2" and "using namespace cocos2d" ? and what is the purpose of the #else statement if they declare the same macros as in the "ifdef ___cplusplus" ?

Comment: `namespace cocos2 { /*your code*/ }` establish the namespace for the code inside of the brackets, so all the symbols (global variables, classes, functions) you add is going to be added to that namespace. As a game dev, when you are not the owner of the namespace, it is not a good idea to `use namespace cocos2d {}` as you may encounter name conflicts.

`using namespace cocos2d` on the other hand, just eliminate the need to write the namespace name `cocos2d::` on the left-hand side of all symbols from cocos2d namespace, but it doesn't add any new symbol to cocos2d namespace.

Comment: Regarding the purpose of the `#else`: what would happen if  `___cplusplus` was not defined, e.g. in a C or Objective-C code? We would have a compilation problem since some symbols like `NS_CC` doesn't exist. That's the reason. `#ifdef __cplusplus ... #else .. #endif` is a mechanism to ensure successful compilation of compilation units that don't support specific C++ features, like namespaces in this scenario.